Normalizing row with sets of columns, handle all nulls?
I want to say up front, I know this is crazy.
I inherited an app I have to maintain from somebody that had denormalized 6 sets of columns into a single row (e.g. some core columns, like ID, 00_c1, 00_c2, 00_c3, 01_c1, 01_c2, 01_c3, 02_c1, 02_c2, 02_c3, etc).
Then he wanted to renormalize those set of columns for the purposes of creating json objects out of the row.
In the original implementation, he wrote a re-normalizing view that used 6 UNION ALLs
e.g.
SELECT ID, '0' as X, 00_c1 as c1, 00_c2 as c2, 00_c3 as c3
FROM table WHERE 00_c1 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, '1' as X, 01_c1 as c1, 01_c2 as c2, 01_c3 as c3
FROM table WHERE 01_c1 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, '2' as X, 02_c1 as c1, 02_c2 as c2, 02_c3 as c3
FROM table WHERE 02_c1 is not null
UNION ALL
...

His jsonizing query looks up the row on ID and then joins to the view on ID with FOR JSON PATH.
It's grossly inefficient, so I was trying to replace the normalizing with CROSS APPLY (VALUES ())
It worked, and it's a lot more efficient, but I'm getting a weird artifact with the VALUES implementation where all the columns in one set are null and I'm getting an empty json object for it.
In other words, not all rows have all 6 sets of columns.  Some may have 3, some 4, etc and the (05_c1, 05_c2, 05_c3) columns will all be null.  The resulting json for that row just comes out {}
Is there any way (either with FOR JSON or VALUES) to ignore a row where all the values are null?
Or is the only real solution to reimplement the whole thing with proper normalization?

I found my way around. It's a bit awkward, but I keep the subquery with the unions, but the outer query establishes row context.  Looks convoluted but it works:
SELECT ID, (
    SELECT ID as [Json.ID],
        [Json.Array] = (
            SELECT X, c1, c2, c3 FROM (
            SELECT '0' as X, 00_c1 as c1, 00_c2 as c2, 00_c3 as c3
            WHERE 00_c1 is not null
            UNION
            SELECT '1' as X, 01_c1 as c1, 01_c2 as c2, 01_c3 as c3
            WHERE 01_c1 is not null
            UNION
            SELECT '2' as X, 02_c1 as c1, 02_c2 as c2, 02_c3 as c3
            WHERE 02_c1 is not null
            UNION
            ...
            ) B FOR JSON PATH
    ) FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) as JSON
FROM table

